# Android EditText, is auto-indentation possible?

Tags: android, android-edittext

For the Android EditText tool, I have a multi-line notepad like program that I also want to implement auto-indentation. Such that, if at one line, I'm 4 spaces in, and in the new line, I want to stay at the same indentation. How could I go about implementing this?

Comment: By writing your own custom view.  That isn't a feature of the built in one.

Comment: It will be too broad to answer, but I think you can listen to enter key. Then analyze the number of spaces at the beginning of the current line. And insert that number of spaces in the new line automatically.

Comment: Get current line using getText().toString() method. Then split the string using .split('\n') method. Then get the last element of the array obtained by splitting.

Comment: Use setText() method to set the string